# SubSonic 3 Linq Joining error after using CleanUp

Tags: c#, .net, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

I am using the ActiveRecord SubSonic3 templates. Everything was working just dandy, then I decided I wanted things to look a bit better. See my database has field that look like this:

```
SomeKey_id
SomeOtherKey_id
```

I wanted to clean it up so that it would instead be

```
SomeKeyID
SomeOtherKeyID
```

when accessing it through SubSonic.

So I added this small thing to the CleanUp function of `settings.ttinclude`

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(result,".*_id",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)){
  result=result.Substring(0,result.Length-3);
  result+="ID";
}
```

Now though everywhere I have joins on an `ID` field it no longer works.

For example:

```
var data=from f in Foo
         join b in Bar on f.FooID equals b.FooID
         select new{FooValue=f, BarValue=b};
```

Does not work.

It will yield this exception:

> The member 'FooID' is not supported

However before I did the `_id` fix it worked perfectly. What is wrong? How do I work around this?

Stacktrace is [at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YXFDDY4u)

Comment: This is probably unconnected to your problem, but your regex is wrong. If you had something called `my_idea`, then the regular expression would match, and then you proceed to replace `dea` with `ID`, yielding `my_iID`. Try using the regex `"_id$"` instead, or even better, just say `if (result.EndsWith("_id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`.

Comment: @Tim yes, unrelated but thanks that works much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in SubSonic.Core as I suspected. I downloaded the source for it and in Schema/DatabaseTable.cs I had to change the `GetColumnByPropertyName` function to something like this:

```
public IColumn GetColumnByPropertyName(string PropertyName)
{
    var c = Columns.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(PropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (c == null)
    {
        c=Columns.SingleOrDefault(x => CleanUpColumnName(x.Name).Equals(PropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (c == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Couldn't find column name");
        }
    }
    return c;
}
private string CleanUpColumnName(string name)
{
    //don't forget to change Settings.ttinclude:CleanUp when changing this function! 
    string result = name;
    if (result.EndsWith("_id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 3);
        result += "RID";
    }
    return result;
}
```

The reason for this is that when it tries to resolve the column name to an IColumn in the appropriate table all it has is something like "FooID" and all the columns have a `.Name` of "Foo_id". So, I made it so that if it doesn't find the column the first time then it will run the CleanUp function the second time on each of the column names so that it can find a match.

If someone from SubSonic reads this, I'd love if you somehow patched this bug or at least gave notice of it. Note the version I'm using(and the source I'm using) is 3.0.0.4

**EDIT:**

Actually it's more complicated than this. I ended up having to add a CleanName field to IColumn and DataColumn in SubSonic and then fill in the CleanName from when the T4 templates run. Then I changed the line above to something like

```
var c = Columns.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CleanName.Equals(PropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Then in lots of random places I had to change code like this:

```
ParameterValue = settings[tbl.PrimaryKey.Name],
```

to code like this:

```
ParameterValue = settings[tbl.PrimaryKey.CleanName],
```

I'm still not sure that I've gotten all the changes complete but I can update, insert, select, and join so I'd say I'm close if not.

Comment: Note I've made an Issue over at SubSonic about this: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/issue/222/

Answer (score 0):

What does the CleanUp function run on? Does it run on the output of the code templates, i.e. the auto-generated C# code that SubSonic generates? Surely you need this auto-generated code to refer to the correct database columns that you are accessing. If your database column is actually called `SomeKey_id` and you change that to `SomeKeyID` in the code, then of course SubSonic will be unable to locate that database column. In other words, how are you making sure that you are replacing only the identifiers that you will be using in C# code, but *not* the identifiers that refer to the database columns?

Comment: CleanUp is an actual function in the T4 template. So when it is generating code it will run CleanUp on certain things such as column and table names. It has two different "names" It has CleanName which is what the .Net name is and it has Name which is the database column name. It only affects CleanName which is suppose to only be for aesthetic purposes

Comment: OK, and I presume you’ve looked at the code that is generated from the template and checked that all the C# identifiers have been replaced and all the DB column names are still intact?

Comment: OK, then I’m out of ideas too, sorry.

Comment: It appears to be caused somewhere inside of the SubSonic.Core assembly source, not the generated code.. The error location inside the assembly's source though is an odd one. I'm not for sure why it would be trying to do it in that way

Comment: I don’t suppose you could post (at pastebin) the entire code file generated by the template?

Comment: @Timwi maybe tomorrow I will create a sample project and do it, but my actual project is proprietary.

Comment: My answer below actually fixes this problem. Apparently they don't completely "support" the cleanup function, at least not where characters are added or removed(as in, only case can be different)